# Code editor skins?

Tags: c++, html, compiler-construction, text, text-editor

This is a kind of unorthodox question. Frankly, I won't lie to you. I am new to programming and am planning to improve myself. I enjoy coding but I need something to keep me going during the down times, so my question is:

Is there such a thing as a code editor skin? A compiler skin?

For example, you have the Command Prompt, it has a black background with white writing, it seems geeky, exactly what I want.

I want a compiler that looks like command prompt...black with white writing (or green) or still has color coding (some compilers change color of text based on command). Yes, this is mainly for boasting, but I don't want to show someone something that basically looks like a text editor, I just want something that looks a little cooler.

P.S (This question may seem a little unnecessary, it is because it is my first question, I'd like to warm up to this community before I start asking some real questions about code.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio is an editor/compiler etc that you can use to do C++ development, and it is highly themeable. You might be interested in http://www.phpvs.net/vs-themes/ and http://techietweaks.blogspot.com/2008/11/visual-studio-themes-gallery.html .

Answer (score 1):

A text editor with a black background still looks like a text editor.

If you want a console-esque editor, look into vim and emacs - though they take some getting used to, once you're proficient with either they are pretty damn awesome.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing Compiler with IDE, the **compiler** is the program that converts your code into machine code/byte-code/etc.

The **IDE** is the editor itself, which usually works alongside the compiler.

For just **text-editing** you can use [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/). Then you can use the Style Configurator to change to default skins or make your own.

For a **complete IDE**, I recommend [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) especially if you're just starting out. You can change themes on Preferences.